# Can I get clock seconds tick event in OS X programming?

Tags: xcode, macos, timer

I want some operation executed every second. I do not want ticks to be accurate between every two seconds. But for a long term, I want them exact for average.

For example, the ticks may happen in time sequence like this:
0.999, 2.005, 2.995, 3.950, 5.012, ... 999.01, 1000.011, ...
Functions may not executed exactly per second, but in a long term, there would be no (or little enough) error in average.

A simple way is using NSTimer. But there is a problem: If CPU ratio is high, the NSTimer fires with a tinny delay. For example, it may fires as a sequence like this:
1.001, 2.002, 3.004, 4.005, 5.006, ... 999.999, 1001.001, ...
As time elapses, the time error may go more and more greater.

Therefore, is there any way to capture any time elapse event in Xcode? Something like "*NSTimeNotificationSecondPassed*" or ...?

Comment: No. OS X is not a real-time OS.

Comment: For how long would you need that timer to be accurate?

Comment: @zneak Oh, sorry, my expression error. I do not want every second to be accurate. For example, as time elapses for 1000 seconds, I want my app notified 1000 times. Whether or not each seconds post a notification at exact time is not important.

Comment: Then I guess I wasn't clear either. I'd like to know for how long you expect your program to run.

Comment: @zneak How long the application may run is not important. My question shown two examples of the situation that 1000 seconds had elapsed. It is hard to express my idea, but just as Jonathon Reinhart mentioned, OS X is not a read-time OS, it may be hard enough for me to achieve my goal. Anyway, thank you all the same!

Comment: How long your application runs *is* important precisely because OS X is not a real-time OS. There are several different timer technologies you can use, and there are several ways you can adjust your timing if it's off.

Comment: @zneak My application receives a live video streaming (for a day, or a week, or even longer) and I want to count the fps in live. And that is where I want a second-tick event. You remind me that OS X is not a real-time OS. This is important. I will just use scheduled NSTimer to achieve my goal, as the fps counting accuracy is not a critical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have develop a method to achieve my goal:

1. Create an thread Like This:

   ```
   - (void)_threadHandleTick:(id)arg
   {
       while(...)
       {
           @autoreleasepool
           {
               [self sleepToNextSecond];
               ...     /* Do what ever you like or raise a noification */    
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Then the **- sleepToNextSecond** method:

```
    - (void)sleepToNextSecond
    {
        NSDateFormatter *microSecondFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [microSecondFormat setDateFormat:@"SSSSSS"];

        NSString *microSecondString = [microSecondFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        useconds_t microSeconds = 1000000 - ((useconds_t)[microSecondString integerValue]);

        usleep(microSeconds);
    }
```

Done.